# How to register generated resources in Android Gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

I am trying to generate some Android resources in a Gradle task.

I've written a task which parses an input file, and writes out an XML file to a location under the app's `build` directory.

**app/build.gradle**

```groovy
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder


task generateSomeAppResources {
    ext.outputDir = new File(projectDir, "build/generated/res/values")
    doFirst {
        mkdir outputDir

        new File(outputDir, "generated.xml").withWriter { writer ->
            def destXml = new MarkupBuilder(new IndentPrinter(writer, "    ", true, true))
            destXml.setDoubleQuotes(true)
            def destXmlMkp = destXml.getMkp()
            destXmlMkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")
            destXmlMkp.comment("Generated at ${new Date()}")
            destXmlMkp.yield "\r\n"

            destXml.resources() {
                "string"("name": "generated_app_resource") {
                    destXmlMkp.yield("Some generated value for the app")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, and the generated output looks like I expect.

**generated.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated at Wed Feb 12 12:46:12 GMT 2020 -->
<resources>
    <string name="generated_app_resource">Some generated value for the app</string>
</resources>
```

I am struggling to get the Android build system to detect the generated file, though. [Google's advice](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148567878#comment5) is

> to write a task that outputs a generated resource directory structure with whatever you need, use BaseVariant.registerGeneratedResFolders()

But documentation on `registerGeneratedResFolders()` is non-existent. After much tedious searching I found some example usages in the [Play Services Plugin source](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/blob/9a74597756eb567e0387b1b1dd44fd8b2b505c91/oss-licenses-plugin/src/main/groovy/com/google/android/gms/oss/licenses/plugin/OssLicensesPlugin.groovy#L64-L67), for example, so I tried to add something along those lines.

**app/build.gradle**

```groovy
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def files = project.files(generateSomeAppResources.outputDir)
    files.builtBy(generateSomeAppResources)
    variant.preBuildProvider.configure { dependsOn(generateSomeAppResources) }
    variant.mergeResourcesProvider.configure { dependsOn(generateSomeAppResources) }
    variant.registerGeneratedResFolders(files)
}
```

But I'm missing something. The generated resource shows up purple in Android Studio, meaning that the IDE thinks it exists...

[image]

...but the code fails to compile with an `Unresolved reference: generated_app_resource` error.

I don't know what magic incantations are needed to make the Android build system pick up these resources. How do I get this to build?

Comment: I think your generation task does change file but then it doesn't invalidate **R.java** file that tracks those resource id entries. So you should also consider invalidating R file as well so that it does provide compilation error after refresh.

Comment: Does it build with _Gradle_ on commandline?

Comment: @tynn No, it wouldn't build at all.

Comment: As per the accepted answer, it turned out that the folder passed to `registerGeneratedResFolders` should be the parent `res` folder, not the `res/values` folder where the generated file lives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create resources, android requires

1) A resource directory above `values` folder then you can add desired resources as per your requirement

2) Instruct the build process to add the generated resources while building `R.java`

So first configure your build resource task like:

```
task generateSomeAppResources {
    ext.outputDir = new File(projectDir, "build/generated/res/custom/values")
    print("path is "+projectDir)
    doFirst {
        mkdir outputDir

        new File(outputDir, "strings.xml").withWriter { writer ->
            def destXml = new MarkupBuilder(new IndentPrinter(writer, "    ", true, true))
            destXml.setDoubleQuotes(true)
            def destXmlMkp = destXml.getMkp()
            destXmlMkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")
            destXmlMkp.comment("Generated at ${new Date()}")
            destXmlMkp.yield "\r\n"

            destXml.resources() {
                "string"("name": "generated_app_resource") {
                    destXmlMkp.yield("Some generated value for the app")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now add the path in the build process using `sourceSets` in `build.gradle`(app) like

```
android {
    //....
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs += [
                    'build/generated/res/custom',
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, add the task in the current build process as

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn('generateSomeAppResources')
} // no need of `android.applicationVariants.all...`
```

Now sync the project and it will work as expected.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: So you pointed me in the right direction. I didn't realise that the folder I specify in  
`registerGeneratedResFolders` should be the parent `res` folder, not the `res/values` folder where the generated file lives. This was the missing piece of the puzzle for me, so bounty awarded. With that fixed, I didn't need to alter `srcDirs`. Still lamenting the woeful lack of documentation from Google.

Comment: I am glad that I could help, though I didn't want to use `res` because it's auto-generated so don't want to touch it. As you have mentioned, it will work with the right symmetry,  `res` with `values/strings.xml` without `srcDirs` unless someone uses a different resource directory.

Comment: Making task depend on `preBuild` is bad advice, this will execute/check it on each build even when the current task doesn't depend on having resources at all. Better to depend on specific tasks, or use `registerGeneratedResFolders` as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Example on how to generate resources using `BaseVariant.registerGeneratedResFolders`

```
def generateResourcesTask = tasks.register("generateResources", GenerateResourcesTask)
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.registerGeneratedResFolders(
        project.files(generateResourcesTask.map { it.outputDir })
    )
}
```

Using `tasks.register(...)`, `project.files(...)` and `TaskProvider.map(...)` utilizes task avoidance api, and automatically wires up tasks dependencies. `registerGeneratedResFolders` also automatically adds resources to sourceset, so that you can reference generated resources in your code.

```kotlin
abstract class GenerateResourcesTask : DefaultTask() {

    // If you need inputs
    // @get:InputFiles
    // lateinit var inputs: FileCollection

    @get:OutputDirectory
    val outputDir = File(project.buildDir, "generated/res/regenerate/")

    private val outputFile = File(outputDir, "values/missingRes.xml")

    @TaskAction
    fun action() {
        val result = buildString {
            appendln(
                """
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <resources>
                """.trimIndent()
            )

            appendln("""    <string name="test_string">Test string</string>""")

            appendln("</resources>")
        }

        outputFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
        outputFile.writeText(result)
    }
}
```

You can define this task class in build.gradle file, or in buildSrc.
Using annotations like `@OutputFile` makes your task incremental.
For more info no what annotations do and how to use them check out [gradle's documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_input_output_annotations).  You can also use [Runtime API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_input_output_runtime_api) to create tasks with properties.